# sysctl() on dev.cpu.0.freq_levels

Tags: cpu, intel, freebsd, clock, sysctl

On a FreeBSD v13 box, I call `sysctl()` to obtain `dev.cpu.0.freq_levels` which then returns:

```
dev.cpu.0.freq_levels: 3201/84000 3200/84000 3000/76349 2900/73036 2700/66595
2500/60408 2300/53689 2200/50804 2000/45218 1800/39849 1700/37248 1500/31535
1300/26734 1100/22147 1000/19936 800/15661
```

I understand that these are `frequency/wattage` pairs.

Why is there an entry for both 3201MHz and 3200MHz?

All the other entries, are neat multiples of 100, but the first entry is not?
What is going on here?

This is for a [Core i5-4570](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75043/intel-core-i54570-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-60-ghz.html) CPU.

The spec-sheet list a 84W CPU with a base clock of 3.20GHz and a turbo clock of 3.60GHz (which is not present in the freq_levels setting?)

Was the 3.6GHz turbo frequency mistaken as 3.201?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A frequency 1 MHz higher than the maximum frequency of the CPU indicates the Intel(R) Turbo Boost(TM) feature.